# Is having a function as parameter for function like this syntactically acceptable?

Tags: javascript, parameters, return

I am trying to keep my development as modular and easy to use as possible, but I feel this might be taking it too far.

I am calling a function that uses a function which returns data as a parameter, which also uses a function that returns data. So they are nested as such:

```
append_vid(
    compile_data(
        request_data(vid_id)
    )
);
```

So, `request_data()` returns an object which `compile_data` uses to return another object to `append_vid()`.

I am wondering if this is syntactically acceptable, since I have never seen someone nest functions as parameters like this before. Is there a more efficient or standardized method of achieving this without loosing the modularity of separate functions.

Comment: It's syntactically acceptable if it doesn't result in a syntax error. The parameter to a function may be any expression of arbitrary complexity, including of course one involving another function call. I don't know why you would be looking for a "more efficient or standardized method" of doing this. By the way, your code has nothing to do with callbacks or modularity, however you understand that.

Comment: That's an argument not a parameter, and a call not a function. But yes, that's totally standard (sans the indentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is completely valid syntax. If you are looking at synchronous calls.

```js
function MethodOne(value) {
  console.log(value);
}

function MethodTwo(value) {
  console.log(value);
  return value * 4;
}

function MethodThree(value) {
  console.log(value);
  return value * 2;
}

MethodOne(
  MethodTwo(
    MethodThree(1)
  )
);
```

If you values are being returned from a async call, then you have to change the method signature and use promises. Here is an example for Async.

```js
function MethodOne(value) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      value = value * 4;
      console.log(value);
      resolve(value);
    }, 1000);
  });
  return promise;
}

function MethodTwo(value) {

  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      value = value * 2;
      console.log(value);
      resolve(value);
    }, 1000);
  });

  return promise;
}

function MethodThree(value) {
  console.log(value);
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(1)
    }, 1000);
  });
  return promise;

}

MethodThree(1).then(MethodTwo).then(MethodOne);
```

Comment: Ended up doing a bit of research into promises; very handy since I am dealing with an ajax request.